# Why is the field values are posted twice on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I'm working on dynamically changing a the textfields based on radiobutton selection.
If I select single, then it should display different kinds of fields in the form and when I select multi it has different.

To achieve this,
I created two div's to fit the elements which gets changed on radiobutton selection.
I put the textfields in first div(id="single") and repeated the same fields in second field in another div(id="multi").

Based on radio button selection this works, but when I submit the form the values I have the below problem:

1. When I select single, the form displays all fields required, but the submitted values are sent twice, i.e. in console I see two entries sent,
   I guess it is taking the fields of multi as well.
2. But when I select multi it works fine, still I see two entries in POST of console.
   How can I avoid this. Is it the right way of handling such situations or is there anything other than this.
   [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4tKEL/)

Console:

```
Ivrmapping[WelcomeNotes]    
Ivrmapping[audioWelcomeUr...    
Ivrmapping[audioWelcomeUr...    
Ivrmapping[groupZCode]  Ba
Ivrmapping[groupzName]  
Ivrmapping[groupzName]  
Ivrmapping[ivrnumber]   123467901
Ivrmapping[language]    
Ivrmapping[language]    0
Ivrmapping[selectionList]   
Ivrmapping[selectionList]
```

Comment: I have created a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Do something like:

```
$("#multi_language > input").attr('disabled', true);
$("#single_language > input").attr('disabled', false);
```

Disabling inputs remove them from request.

Comment: I added this along with hide() and show() functions, but still the same.

Comment: This is just example. You need to choose appropriate field types like textarea.

Answer (score 0):

The name attribute of your fields need to be different in a form control in order to differentiate the values in the request.  This does not help you NOT send values across that aren't being used, but it lets you distinguish on the server side which values are for which radio button selection.

Comment: You are saying the name should be different in both the divs

Comment: `<div><input id="nameText" name=
</div>`

Comment: `<div id="single"><input id="firstNameSingle" name="firstNameSingle" type="text"/><input id="lastNameSingle" name="lastNameSingle" type="text"/></div>` for the single div, and `<div id="multi"><input id="firstNameMulti" name="firstNameMulti" type="text"/><input id="lastNameMulti" name="lastNameMulti" type="text"/></div>` -- the `name` attribute must be different on each input control in order to know which value you are looking at in the request.

Comment: @bdparrish partially true. you aren't forced to distinguish form fields names. As I said in my answer you can disable field to remove it from request: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp

Comment: @Zentoaku - I don't disagree, I was giving him another option to distinguish his values on the server side, but yes you can absolutely call 15 different input controls with the same name.